# add const value to sql query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM table(i#1040_inv_adj_fn('123'))
```

how to add const value? This example doesn't work:

```
SELECT *, 'John' Name FROM table(i#1040_inv_adj_fn('123'))
```

error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9
```

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a valid Oracle error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you did not tell us what the error is we have to guess. My guess is you need an alias for the table function, otherwise the `*` isn't legal:

```
SELECT  t.*, 
        'Name' as John  
FROM table(i#1040_inv_adj_fn('123')) t
```

Comment: If you dont want to use table alias then you need to use column names in query